# Confirm dialog with ok/cancel

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I am using a WebForms GridView control. When a user clicks "Update" on a row, I want to check the values they entered against some other records.

From that, if I return true, I'd like to display a confirm dialog asking the user if they'd like to continue with their update.

A javascript confirm dialog probably won't work because I don't always want to show this dialog, only when the values entered meet a certain condition.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using the `RowDataBound` event to check for those conditions and add the confirmation dialog where needed.

**EDIT :** Compare dates and show a confirmation if they're different

See this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XjypN/4/) for a demonstration.

```
<script type="text/javascript">        
   validateInput = function(inputDate, compareDate, confirmButtonID) {           
       var confirmButton = document.getElementById(confirmButtonID);       
       if (confirmButton) {               
           $(confirmButton).one("click", function() {
               var result = dates.compare(inputDate, compareDate);
               if (result != 0){ //change to suit your needs
                   return confirm("Are you sure you want to save these changes?");        
               }
               return true;
           });                                                                                 
       }
    }             
</script>
```

And here's the code for the `dates` class used for the comparison ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/497790)):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var dates = {
        convert:function(d) {
            return (
                d.constructor === Date ? d :
                d.constructor === Array ? new Date(d[0],d[1],d[2]) :
                d.constructor === Number ? new Date(d) :
                d.constructor === String ? new Date(d) :
                typeof d === "object" ? new Date(d.year,d.month,d.date) :
                NaN
            );
        },
        compare:function(a,b) {
            return (
                isFinite(a=this.convert(a).valueOf()) &&
                isFinite(b=this.convert(b).valueOf()) ?
                (a>b)-(a<b) :
                NaN
            );
        },
        inRange:function(d,start,end) {
           return (
                isFinite(d=this.convert(d).valueOf()) &&
                isFinite(start=this.convert(start).valueOf()) &&
                isFinite(end=this.convert(end).valueOf()) ?
                start <= d && d <= end :
                NaN
            );
        }
    }
</script>
```

In the `RowDataBound` event of the `GridView`, assign the `onchange` function for each row:

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    var inputCtrl = e.Row.FindControl("txtEnteredDate") as TextBox;
    if (inputCtrl != null)
    {
        var updateButtonCtrl = e.Row.FindControl("btnUpdate") as Button;
        if (updateButtonCtrl != null)
        {
            inputCtrl.Attributes["onchange"] = string.Format("return validateInput(this.value, '{0}', '{1}');", DataBinder.Eval("DateToCompare"), updateButtonCtrl.ClientID);
        }
    }
}
```

**jQuery Confirmation Dialog**

If you need something more flexible than a regular JavaScript confirm dialog, you can change the above to use the [jQuery UI Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/modal-confirmation.html) as a confirmation instead.

Comment: This event wouldn't work as I don't know that value the user wants to change to until they click the "Edit" link, update that value then click "Update"

Comment: So you want to show the confirmation based on what the user entered into the field? For example, show the confirmation if the user changes the value in a TextBox?

Comment: Yes.. I have a text box with a CalendarExtender. If a user changes the date to something that overlaps the date with another record, I don't want to commit the change until the user confirms that they know this change will cause records to be deleted.

Comment: @MichaelWarren: Edited my answer and provided a solution to compare dates and add a conditional confirmation.

Comment: What do you mean? If the user clicks "OK" the dialog returns true, otherwise it returns false. The code above just returns the value of the confirmation assuming that when they click "OK" you want to perform the postback and update the records.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9872/discussion-between-michael-warren-and-james-johnson)

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear and for that I apologize. I don't always want to show a dialog when the user changes that date field. I'd like to show the dialog when that date change meets certain criteria. Then if the user acknowledges that they are aware of the overlap in the date they entered with another date in the grid, then I can continue with the update on that row.

Comment: That's what this does. It only shows the confirmation when the input date is different than the compare date. You can modify this as needed to only show the confirmation when the date is smaller or larger by changing `if (result != 0)` to `if (result < 0)` or `if (result > 0)`

Comment: I appreciate your help, but I don't think you understand what I am trying to get at. A user enters a new date, then I need to query the database with that date to see if it violates my rules for this screen(actually happens pretty rarely). If it does, I want to display a confirmation box asking to continue with deleting those records it violated. So I need to get that result back to the server so that I can complete the delete.

Comment: Can you query the database and retrieve the minimum or maximum acceptable date in the `RowDataBound` event, and use that date to compare against? If you want to avoid a postback when the user clicks the button, you'll need to have that logic in place beforehand.

Comment: If you can't get the date in the `RowDataBound` event, then you'll need to send an `ID` into the `validateInput` function and execute an AJAX call to check whether the entered date is valid.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using WebForms (?), you need to add some validation controls to the GridView template.

Here is an [example from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb426882.aspx) using a `CompareValidator`:

```
<EditItemTemplate>
    <asp:TextBox ID="EditUnitPrice" runat="server"
      Text='<%# Bind("UnitPrice", "{0:c}") %>'
      Columns="6"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:CompareValidator ID="CompareValidator1" runat="server"
        ControlToValidate="EditUnitPrice"
        ErrorMessage="The price must be greater than or equal to zero and
                       cannot include the currency symbol"
        Operator="GreaterThanEqual" Type="Currency"
        ValueToCompare="0">*</asp:CompareValidator>
</EditItemTemplate>
```

Comment: I am using WebForms, and my validation requires having to query the database.